# Data structure to store and retrieve a mapping between one action and multiple verbs in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

What type of data structure must I use to build a dictionary like structure where one type of action is mapped to multiple verbs?

> Example: Action1 will be mapped to verb1, verb2,verb5 and  Action2
>   will be mapped to verb3,verb4.

Each action can have a varied number of verbs attached to it. The linking between action and Verbs will be hard coded.

Also, I need to search for a verb inputted by the user in the verb list defined and displayed in the corresponding action name:

> Example: If the user input is verb 4 the system must return Action2

Comment: What are the actual use cases here?  Do you only need the ability to lookup a verb and obtain an action, or would you also need the ability to lookup an action and find a verb?

Comment: use two maps like `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` one of `action: verbs` and one of `verb: actions` that way you can search by both action and verb

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap for this, the key would be the action and value would be the list of verbs:

```
 Map<String,List<String>> actionVerbMap=new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

That sound like a Map of action and verb set

```
Map<String, Set<String>> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
```

Use set to store verbs ensures the uniqueness and give good performance when you want to find action by given verb

```
Set<String> action1Verb = new HashSet<>();
action1Verb.add("verb1");
action1Verb.add("verb2");
....
dictionary.put(action1, action1Verb);
dictionary.put(action2, action2Verb);
```

To search for action by verbs:

```
String action = dictionary.keySet().stream()
          .filter(key -> dictionary.get(key).contains("verb"))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);
```

If you don't care much about memory usage, I suggest you to use two maps to store:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> dictionary to store action -> set of verbs
Map<String, String> verbMap to store verb -> action
```

In that case, search action by verb is superfast like:

```
String action = verbMap.get("verb")
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example for how to code it ? Sorry I am new to programmimg

Answer (score 0):

I think a `HashMap<String, Action>` will be suitable.

Since you want to use the verbs to access the actions but not vice versa, the verbs should be the keys.

Here are some example mappings:

```
verb1 -> Action1
verb2 -> Action1
verb5 -> Action1
verb3 -> Action2
verb4 -> Action2
```

This way you can ensure that no verb refers to two actions because keys are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Data structure depends on relationship between verbs and actions. What is your relationship between verbs and action? 1-N N-N or N-1?

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact dictionary like data structure, go for ***Prefix Tree*** or ***Trie***. If there are **n** Number of keys and **m** is the Length of the key then Trie has Time Complexity of *O(m)*.

Trie is preferrable if there is some lexicographical order or similar prefixes in your verbs.

```
                     t
                   /   \
                te     ta
               /  \      \
             tea  ten    tar
```

[Leetcode: Prefix Tree](https://leetcode.com/articles/implement-trie-prefix-tree/)

[Wikipedia: Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

If that is not the case then ***HashMap*** is suitable option as described in other answers.